# How to passthrough argument from npm script to json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to passthrough argument from my custom npm script to json file, but I don't any idea how do that. I want to use custom npm script which run specific url or enviroment, for example:

```
scripts: {
  "dev": "node run something(and send dev as argument)",
  "prod": "node run something(and send prod as argument)"
}
```

and in some json file I have "Url" field, for example:

```
{
  "url": "https://{sent argument}.com"
}
```

How to passthrough this argument into url?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for [environment variables](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html).

Comment: @Toby thanks! But when I used command MY_VAR=dev node some_file.js I had error: ``` 'MY_VAR' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ``` Do you have an idea what's going on?